# SharePoint 2010 Search is not working

Tags: 2010, search

Search in my SP2010 environment is not working. The ULS log file is long & so I am posting in part here.

> SharePoint Server Search          Query                           dk9x    High        SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetLocationConfigurations--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://server:32843/3966a8bf4a4e4e338fda8adb4980a596/SearchService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.C...  5291a5f1-f08b-4d00-8dcd-cf5ab38361f6

**The complete log has been uploaded [here](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=D7BA3A048EF1E1C5&resid=D7BA3A048EF1E1C5!177)**

Please have a look at the file above & provide solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a Search Service Application Application ? The SearchService.svc comes along with it normally.

Comment: Yes We do have a search application!

Comment: Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: When you put this adresse in your browser, what does it say ? http://server:32843/3966a8bf4a4e4e338fda8adb4980a596/SearchService.svc

Comment: Error
Internal server error exception:

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 04468cd3-e7a2-4e28-b5fe-ae1b8af8069a

Date and Time: 11/07/2011 14:11:04

Comment: Have you tried to recreate a new Search Service Application?

Comment: please check the log files with the correlation id : 04468cd3-e7a2-4e28-b5fe-ae1b8af8069a

Answer (score 2):

Saumil,
   Here is a helpful post that you can run through the steps to verify your search in SharePoint 2010 is configured properly.

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/search-configuration-in-sharepoint-2010/

My guess is that it has something to do with credentials of your Search Service Application.